# CNOT gate with trapped ions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, ions, ion-traps

I'm interested in knowing the structure of a CNOT gate, in quantum computing. THe problem with that is, that I've read how the structure of a nuclear quantum computer works, but I still don't understand how that can be implemented to create a quantum CNOT gate. I've read the article of the original proposal of Cirac-Zoller, but it wasn't explained very good, I guess, so I want to ask, if someone has a link to some publication where it's explained better than there, possibly with more pictures rather then formulas. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean a nuclear-spin QC? I have not heard of suggestion of a nuclear QC, which would be a different "beast", indeed! Just curious... are there actually suggestions to use the nuclear force for quantum computing? Cirac-Zoller were proposing computing with atomic states, I believe, but they were adapting techniques that had been used in nuclear-spin-resonance before, which is not very far fetched. Even I did a student experiment with optical magnetic resonance. It's quite cute to see an optical spin echo!

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/173776/how-is-cnot-operation-realized-physically

Comment: Since a CNOT gate is a manipulation in a seven-dimensional space, I'm not aware of any simple pictorial representation, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

*Quantum Computing Devices: Principles, Designs, and Analysis*, (2007) provides the background theory, followed by a chapter for each of the technologies that was actively being explored when it was prepared.

The experimental chapters provide detailed information that ties the experimental apparatus to its mathematical representation.  I recommend this a a good starting point.