# Intuition behind quantum CNOT gate applied to a pair of electrons

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, quantum-computer

I'm looking for some intuition behind how a cNOT gate works.  I think I understand the mathematics; but, I'm having trouble imagining how two electrons would interact to produce the predicted result.

If I understand correctly, the input to a cNOT gate is two unentangled electrons. I picture these as two Bloch spheres with vectors pointing in arbitrary directions.

To implement a cNOT gate, we would (1) bring these two electrons close enough to become entangled, (2) prevent electron `x` from rotating in the z direction (thereby preserving its state in that direction), and (3) allow electron `y` to rotate (which changes the probably of measuring it in the up state with respect to the z axis).

My understanding is that entanglement is a result of electrons rotating to align their spin axes into a lower energy state.  If that's the case, why is electron `y` affected more when electron `x`'s axis is pointed up than when it's pointed down?   It would make sense if the effect was symmetric (large when the angle is close to either 0 or $\pi$, and small when it is close to $\frac{\pi}{2}$), but given that `y` can be oriented either up or down, I don't see how the effect of `x` can be small with oriented up and large when oriented down.

This post addresses the implementation of cNOT, but from a perspective that seems more mathematical than intuitive. [How is CNOT operation realized physically?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/173776/how-is-cnot-operation-realized-physically)

This video gives the type of answer I was looking for: https://youtu.be/EjdIMBOWCWo?t=30 (I would have added this as the answer; but, I can't while the post is marked as a duplicate.)

Comment: Sounds like a better title to your question might be "Implementation of quantum cNOT gates?". I think that that's a good question. I've read through some material on quantum cNOT gates but the material that I've read never actually describes how such a gate would be physically implemented.

Comment: I avoided that title, because I wanted something more intuitive than mathematical.  I found this answer yesterday; but, it's a bit over my head: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/173776/

Comment: the selected answer says the key is to switch the interaction on and off in a controllable way, and I agree. Imagine that you can flip between states $|0>$ and $|1>$ using microwaves, but state $|1>$ is an interacting state (e.g. its scattering length is large so that contact interaction becomes strong when two atoms in $|1>$ are on top of each other). Prepare two atoms in $|0>$ in optical tweezers. Now flip control atom to $|1>$  and overlap the tweezers. Because of interaction, the microwave resonance is shifted and you won't see spin flips when you shine the microwaves.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is CNOT operation realized physically?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/173776/)